# Maven Enforcer Plugin: Specify rules via command line

Tags: maven, command-line, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-enforcer-plugin

I want to execute the [Maven Enforcer plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html) via the command line.

I've tried:

```
mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=[requireReleaseDeps]
mvn enforcer:enforce -Drules=requireReleaseDeps
```

I am always getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (default-cli) on project lkww-util-app-wurm-admin-rs-api: The parameters 'rules' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce are missing or invalid -> [He
lp 1]
```

How do I have to specify the `rules` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enforcer plugin does not allow rules to be chosen/engaged via command line parameters.

There is an [open issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-142) against the plugin for this so you could vote for that.

In the meantime, if your choice of rules can be categorised into a small number of choices then you could perhaps create profiles and associate rules with profiles thereby allowing a build to be run for a selected subset of rules by specifying a profile. In the example below there are two profiles, each of which has a different enforcer rule:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>EnforceBannedPlugins</id>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-banned-plugins</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <bannedPlugins>
                                    ...
                                </bannedPlugins>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>EnforceMavenVersion</id>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven-version</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    ...
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Of course, this is only a runner if your requirement to specify enforcer rules at runtime can be satisfied by a few canned configurations. If, however, the requirement is to support **any** possible enforcer rule then you're out of luck because the plugin does not support that.

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using profiles, as recommended in another answer, you can also pre-configure your `<executions>` in the main section of your POM and then use the `<execution>`’s `<id>` to invoke them from the command line (see the [Guide to Configuring Plug-ins](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) for more info on this syntax):

```
mvn enforcer:enforcer@my-execution-id
```

As any `<execution>` of the [`enforce` goal](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html) by defaults binds the goal to the `validate` phase, however, the `my-execution-id` execution also runs on a normal `mvn clean install`. If that is not desired, configure the execution with [`<skip>true</true>`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html#skip) and override this on the command-line:

```
mvn enforcer:enforcer@my-execution-id -Denforcer.skip=false
```

Whether this is clearer than spreading the `maven-enforcer-plugin` configuration across the POM’s main section and `<profiles>` is a matter of personal preference.